# How do I add an Instance of a class I created to a MultipartEntity?

Tags: java, android, multipartentity

So I have a class Workout that I created and I would like to send it to a server using HttpPost. Is there a way I could add that class to  a MultipartEntity or how should I post it?

Comment: @duffymo , multipartentity seems to be a mime api here.

Comment: Ah!  Thank you!  http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntity.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your class must implement java.io.Serializable.

```
        MultipartEntity e = new MultipartEntity();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        oos.writeObject(yourserializableobject);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
        InputStreamBody isb = new InputStreamBody(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()), "o");
        e.addPart("o", isb);
```